# Tail log backup or use log backup after putting DB into single user mode?

Tags: sql-server

I plan to migrate existing SQL Server 2008 DB to new server (has 2017 engine) with minimum down time.  I will do full restore, then log restores (all with norecovery) on the new server up until the time of migration.  I have tested the restore process using my plan which is this:

For the final log backup, my plan now is to set the database into single user mode, then do a "regular" log backup. Do I need to do the "tail" log backup (add NORECOVERY option) while taking this last log backup? if so, then why? If the DB is set into single user mode which means that no one except me can access database, can I omit using NORECOVERY?  I use Ola's scripts to do log backups, and would rather just run my "regular" log backup job after the DB is in single user mode, copy that backup to the new server, and do the final restore.

Bottom line - is there a difference between log backup in single user mode and a tail log backup?

Comment: I did something similar once. But I created a "log shipping" task, then after the last log was moved, we just turned off the software for some seconds, changed connection string and then we turned on the system again. It took like 10 seconds to migrate a 4TB database. It was aewsome.( damm I hate english past tenses).

Comment: Have you considered setting the database to `READ_ONLY` before your final log backup - then setting the restored database back to `read_write`?  I will say that setting the database to single-user-mode can _sometimes_ be problematic because some other process _steals_ that single connection and you're scrambling to get your task done with _a minimum of downtime_.

Comment: You could set up mirroring for the database and then just perform manual failover to the new instance.

Answer (score 2):

> If the DB is set into single user mode which means that no one except me can access database, can I omit using NORECOVERY?

If you are connected to a different database, or when you eventually disconnect any other user can access the SINGLE_USER database.  A Tail Log backup leaves the database in the RESTORING state.  This guarantees that no users can accidentally read or write data to the old database after the cut-over.

Answer (score 1):

All that NORECOVERY does is to make it *impossible* to generate any log records after this backup was produced. If you feel that you have sufficient control to handle that you don't miss any work done on the "old" side, then by all means - you can skip this option.

This is from a technical standpoint. You might consider it being a bonus that it is *impossible* to do any further modifications, or that the old database is in restoring state. But that is more of a management thing.

Comment: >>>All that NORECOVERY does is to make it impossible to generate any log records after this backup was produced.<<< This sounds like NORECOVERY permits any readonly access to the database (no log generation in this case), but it's not true: database in restoring state cannot be accessed at all

Comment: @sepupic True, I should have been more specific. I was referring to what type of backup it performs. There is nothing special about the type of log backup that you produce when using NORECOVERY compared to not using that option. It is just a guarantee, that it is impossible to produce any more log records.